Apache Airflow Rest API Authentication
We have AWS Managed Apache Airflow. I need to get metadata of the DAGS using Airflow Rest API.How to authenticate AWS Managed Apache Airflow UI interface URL? Can we use API Key? If I need to support API key what needs to be done in Airflow settings as well as in POSTMAN and Python scrip?
I am using Airflow 2.7.2 version.

you can try using [1] Airflow API (Stable)and try the API [2] and to auth you can use [3]
[1] https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html
[2] https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_dags
[3] https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Authentication

I have already seen this doc. This shows airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth. Will it support only basic authentication, will it wont support api keyfor authentication?
